# do all matrices with $\det(A)=\pm 1$ form a group under multiplication?

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory

all matrices with determinant one form the special linear group.
it is explained that because $\det(A) \det(B)=\det(AB)$ it is closed as $1*1=1$
and because the general linear group is a group, and special linear group is a part of the general one, and because all of the inverses must have determinant 1 and also be in the special linear group, the inversion axiom holds.
doesn't this also hold for the group of matrices defined by $\det(A)= \pm 1$?
$$(1)(1)=1,(-1)1=-1,1(-1)=-1,(-1)(-1)=1$$
so it is closed.can a similar argument to the special linear group prove this is a group?
can anyone provide a counter example or prove this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3623289/a-in-gl-2-mathbb-r-deta-1-is-a-normal-subgroup-of-gl-2-mathbb-r

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yeah, it is a group for the same reasons:

1. If $\det(A),\det(B)\in \{\pm 1\}$, then $\det(AB)=\det(A)\det(B)\in \{\pm 1\}$.
2. If $\det(A)\in \{\pm 1\}$, then $\det(A^{-1})=\det(A)^{-1}\in \{\pm 1\}$.
3. $\det(I_n)=1\in \{\pm 1\}$.

This shows that $\{A\in GL_n(\mathbb{C}):\det(A)\in \{\pm 1\}\}$ is a subgroup of $GL_n(\mathbb{C})$.

Comment: do you know of the name of this group? to me it seems rather special and i believe it probably already has a name.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't. A quick search in an algebra book didn't turn up anything either.

Comment: it seems like it to me too.

Comment: It is generally noted $SL^{\pm}_n(\mathbb C)$ https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special_linear_group

Comment: Thank you very much. Can you answer https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3699270/what-s-the-name-of-this-type-of-matrix-group ?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, the set $$\{A \in GL(n, \Bbb F) : \det A = \pm 1\}$$ of $n \times n$ matrices of determinant $\pm 1$ is a group under matrix multiplication.

**Hint** You already know that $$\det: GL(n, \Bbb F) \to \Bbb F^\ast$$ is a homomorphism. In particular $\det^{-1}(G)$ is a subgroup of $GL(n, \Bbb F)$ for every subgroup $G \leq \Bbb F^\ast$.

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3624970/589

Comment: I am puzzled by the downvote on what I think is a routine answer. Could the downvoter explain their objection?

Comment: (For the fact that $\phi^{-1}(G)$ is a subgroup of $A$ for any group homomorphism $A \to B$ and subgroup $G \leq B$, see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/476508/is-the-pre-image-of-a-subgroup-under-a-homomorphism-a-group.)