# What’s the name of this type of matrix group?

Tags: matrices, group-theory

Let $c$ be a real nonzero Number and n be a natural number.
$$LG_n(c)=\{A \in GL_n(R)|\exists k \in Z(\det(A)=c^k)\}$$
Is $LG_n(c)$ always a well known type of group?
I managed to prove all group axioms.

Answer (score 1):

Note that the determinant map is a surjective group homomorphism from $\mathrm{GL}_n(\mathbb{R})$ to $\mathbb{R}^*$. In particular, given a subgroup of $\mathbb{R}^*$, its inverse image will be a subgroup of $\mathrm{GL}_n(\mathbb{R})$.

Your example is just particular case of this (with the subgroup of $\mathbb{R}^*$ being $\langle c\rangle$.) I'm not sure that these groups have more particular names, usually I've seen them described just as above. For example, your group would be "the inverse image under the determinant map of $\langle c\rangle$". Of course if you are working with them a lot, it makes sense to introduce some kind of notation. Perhaps $\det^{-1}(\langle c\rangle)$ might suffice?